# Hybris backoffice searching of order table

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

How the order report data is being searched in back office. Want to know (how) in which location/java file, the queries with order report filter parameters is getting fired on order table?

Are they being fetched via Flexible search queries or is there any other way to search also?

Answer (score 0):

I don't now exact class but I can give trick for finding it. Add custom interceptor for order item. Run project in debug mode. Add break point to interceptor. When code stop on your breakpoint, check call stack for metod, class, etc.